# Проверить установлен ли пакет с помощью ansible

Tags: ubuntu, debian, автоматизация, проверка

Попробовал с

```
- name: Check if apache is installed
  command: dpkg-query -l apache2-mpm-prefork
  ignore_errors: True
  register: deb_check

- name: Install apache
  apt: pkg=apache2-mpm-prefork state=latest
#  when: deb_check.stdout.find('no packages found') != -1
  when: deb_check.stderr.find('no packages found') != -1
```

Но почему-то получается так, что на одной машине работает, на другой нет, т.е `dpkg-query` отдает разные ответы в разные потоки.

На Ubuntu 14.04 отдает в stdout, на 12.04 отдает в stderr. Помогите, пожалуйста, такой вариант не всегда работает и это не радует.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> на Ubuntu 14.04 отдает в stdout, на 12.04 отдает в stderr

унифицировать можно, перенаправив stderr в stdout:

```
$ command 2>&1
```

или наоборот:

```
$ command 1>&2
```

в приложении к приведённому примеру:

```
$ dpkg-query -l apache2-mpm-prefork 2>&1
```

Comment: спасибо, но это не самый подходящий вариант, нет ли стандартного пути решения с помощью ansible?

Comment: я, конечно, посмотрел в поисковике, что такое *ansible*. насколько я вижу, это не проприетарное п.о.. значит, если оно работает неправильно, можно его исправить. или хотя бы сообщить разработчикам об ошибке.

Comment: вот я вижу у вас строку `command: dpkg-query -l apache2-mpm-prefork`. в конец её разве нельзя добавить перенаправление, чтобы она выглядела как `command: dpkg-query -l apache2-mpm-prefork 2>&1` ?

Comment: можно прикрутить, просто хотелось найти более правильное решение, спасибо и вам, я попробую, ведь совсем забыл про перенаправление потоков!

Answer (score 0):

Ansible - это инструмент который применяет конфигурацию. Прежде чем изменить состояние он его проверяет, т.е. если пакет уже установлен - ansible проверит это и отметит задачу как "без изменений" (в логе она будет "зелёной"). Итого, всё что вам нужно это описать желаемое состояние:

```
- name: Install apache
  apt:
    pkg: apache2-mpm-prefork
    state: latest
```

Остальное ansible сделает сам.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте файл, например check.yml, вставьте код ниже и запустите его через ansible-playbook check.yml

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:  
    - name: "Check if NGINX is installed"
      package_facts:
        manager: "auto"

    - name: "NGINX test result"
      debug: 
        msg: "NGINX found"
      when: "'nginx' in ansible_facts.packages"

    - name: "NGINX test result"
      debug: 
        msg: "NGINX NOT found"
      when: "'nginx' not in ansible_facts.packages"
```